# How to Insert Event in Windows Phone 8 Device Calendar

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application. I need to programmatically insert a event in local calendar of Windows Phone 8. Can any one suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a launcher task for that, it's called the `SaveAppointmentTask`

You can find a small code snippet on the [MSDN page here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207038%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I accept your answer. Can you suggest me how can i update and delete that event?

Comment: Ha good question, no that doesn't seem possible ( or I'm missing something )

Comment: Thanks Depechie for guidance.